# Two Angular Controllers Running At Same Time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is whether it is possible to have two AngularJS controllers run or "control" at the same time. Perhaps some kind of threading or multitasking is possible?

That said, I shall describe the situation and perhaps someone knows a way to solve or implement what I need. I have an app with the main route pointing to "/". Now, on that page, there are a couple of buttons. The first button, called A, turns on a timer (TimerCtrl). Another button, called B, points to a different route, say, "/B".

How can I achieve so that TimerCtrl still runs even if the app route is "/B"? In effect, I want the user to be able to return to the original screen and see that the timer has not skipped a beat.

Comment: Numerous ways to do this. Run the timer in a service so it isn't controller dependent is a simple one

Comment: What if I have several buttons that need to use the timer concurrently? Would the service still work for that?

Comment: Sure... service would hold all the business logic for buttons, interval timer etc. If used a directive for the display would help also. No need to duplicate html and binding methods to service

Comment: Am I correct to think that if two or more DOM elements use the same controller/service, then each time that controller is needed a new instance is created?

Comment: That is correct. That's why service would hold all the timer stuff since it is always available

Comment: Cool. I think I have a direction now. Thanks.

Comment: Could you suggest some other ways of doing this? I think it is not very convenient for my project to do it the described way.

Comment: why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Purely architectural reasons. I am trying to finish the beta version and do not want to re-code a lot of stuff as I am almost done with it. I may re-hash it  for future versions.

Comment: Well using  service is most practical way. Without more details it's very hard to suggest alternative. Especially since you don't want to use the easiest approach